# Extract data fron JSON array using loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

im trying to filter a JSON array response as i only need a small part of the results.

I need to get the players `displayName` only.

Here is the repose for the first player, there can be upto 12 player per match.

I need something that can loop through and extract the names..

```
[displayName] => jonhofun
```

At present the only way i can get the data i need is by doing

```
$player1 = $json11['Response']['data']['entries']['0']['player']['destinyUserInfo']['displayName'];
$player2 = $json11['Response']['data']['entries']['1']['player']['destinyUserInfo']['displayName'];
etc... etc...
```

heres the original response

```
Array
(
[Response] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [period] => 2016-08-20T10:16:46Z
                [activityDetails] => Array
                    (
                        [referenceId] => 3156370656
                        [instanceId] => 5370359303
                        [mode] => 12
                        [activityTypeHashOverride] => 3614615911
                    )

                [entries] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [standing] => 0
                                [score] => Array
                                    (
                                        [basic] => Array
                                            (
                                                [value] => 2190
                                                [displayValue] => 2,190
                                            )

                                    )

                                [player] => Array
                                    (
                                        [destinyUserInfo] => Array
                                            (
                                                [iconPath] => /common/destiny_content/icons/d0d3cd4c26aa1a931d46c4bf720856ba.jpg
                                                [membershipType] => 2
                                                [membershipId] => 4611686018454971653
                                                [displayName] => jonhofun
                                            )

                                        [characterClass] => Warlock
                                        [characterLevel] => 40
                                        [lightLevel] => 322
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use for loop and done!

Comment: I dont know how to do that :( thats the problem.. all it says online is $key => $value but how to i tell it what i want it to get??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the sub array under "entries".

```
foreach ($json11['Response']['data']['entries'] as $entries) {
    $player_names[] = $entries['player']['destinyUserInfo']['displayname'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($player_names);    // Check all player names
```

Comment: Thank-you, this has solved my problem, lease now I'll know in future how write foreach loops.